deploy next.js and prisma app with existing database
I want to deploy a Next.js and Next-auth app with credentials provider and I use Prisma as an ORM.
but my problem is that Prisma can migrate database (or update models by existing DB) only in dev mode so how can I deploy a next and next-auth usng prisma orm that uses an existing database in cpanel?
cause i have an api that handles registering users but i want to use my next app to only authenticate users by that database
I tried to run npx prisma init or other prisma commands in cpanel terminal but it does not work
